# if elif else statement - how to make one work above the others?

Tags: python

Imagine I have a simple if elif else statement like this:

```
List = [a, b, c]

if a in List:
   run code
elif b in List:
   run code
elif 2 in List:
   run code
else:
    run code
```

You can see that A and B are both in the lists and the elif. How do I make the code say that B is more important then A. So if both A and B are in the list it will choose B instead of A?

Comment: Move it up to first?

Comment: Okay but what if this list is really large and some things need to be in a different order?

Comment: ...put them in whichever order you need them to be? Why does the length of the list matter? Please give some more context.

Comment: Your not understanding...say for example b is more important then A. 2 is more important then A  and b is more important then 2. Now imagine we have a third element. 3 is more important then B but less important then A... How does that work?

Comment: It doesn't work, they're not consistent. If I'm not understanding, it's because *you're not explaining*; [edit] the question to clarify. Preferably with a less abstract example.

Comment: The logic works exactly as you would expect. You are saying if `a` is in the list then do this; otherwise do something else. If "do something else" needs to happen in some cases when `a` is in the list then you need to write out these conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The priority is from top to bottom. So just move `b` above `a`:

```
List = [a, b, c]

if b in List:
   run code
elif a in List:
   run code
elif 2 in List:
   run code
else:
    run code
```